# Center image inside a div like setting background position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Are there any ways that we can set a  tag inside a div perfectly center no matter what is the width and height of that div? In other way, I want to set an image position inside a div tag like a center background. For example:

```
.image-wrap {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 720px;
  background: url('some-images.jpg') no-repeat center center / auto 100%;
}
```

I want to set an image inside a div like a background above with auto width and 100% height so that all the important content in an image will be in the center of the div.

```
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="some-images.jpg" alt="some image here"/>
</div>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `transform: translate`

```css
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
.image-wrap img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="some image here"/>
</div>
```

Now, if you want it to behave as `background-size: auto 100%` does, do like this

```css
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-wrap img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x100" alt="some image here"/>
</div>

<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="some image here"/>
</div>
```

And here is a version behaving as `background-size: cover` does

```css
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.image-wrap img {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x100" alt="some image here"/>
</div>

<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="some image here"/>
</div>
```

And this version behaving as `background-size: contain` does

```css
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.image-wrap img {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x100" alt="some image here"/>
</div>

<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="some image here"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe this is the only way rather than using display flex :)

Comment: @HuyLe It is one of them ... simplified it a little as well

Comment: @HuyLe Added a few samples

Answer (score 3):

You can center it easily using flex property. Demo [here](http://codepen.io/sivadass/pen/OWqMYX)

```css
.image-wrap {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  border: dotted 1px #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="some image here"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use a live code snippet to put the demo right in SO.

Comment: Are there any ways beside using flex? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like so:

```css
.image-wrap {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 720px;
  background: url('some-images.jpg') no-repeat center center / auto 100%;
  position: relative;
}
img
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px; /* (EXAMPLE) - value should be half of the image width */
  margin-top: -100px; /* (EXAMPLE) - value should be half of the image height */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="some-images.jpg" alt="some image here"/>
</div>
```

Comment: A better way than using margin left/right is using **transform: translate(-50%, -50%)**. By using that, you don't have to know exactly the width and height of the image :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent-div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 720px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image-wrap {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
you can use like this
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="image-wrap" style="background-image: url('http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/nature/nature-02.jpg')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Pretty sure he got me wrong! :) inside parent-div must be an img tag (<img/>)

Answer (score 0):

This is where FlexBox properties become very useful. You can set `align-items: center;` on a container to (by default) vertically center any child elements. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ks62qtns/

The advantage of this is that you don't need to know the dimensions of any of the elements involved in the layout - which is very useful for responsive designs and/or dynamic content.

Flex properties are [reasonably well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=align-items) in modern browsers. You might need fallbacks to support older versions of IE (if you need to)

## HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>
    Content. Any Content.
    </h1>
    <p>
    I might have anything in me!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background: #EEE;

  /* This is just to make a big container. You can set the dimensions however you like.*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  background: #89D485;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most over thought out problem that most developers run into.
If the object is inside another object you are able to just use margin: 0 auto; inside the CSS. This will make the left and right ways to line up correct. This also then works for all media queries from small screen to large screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to calculate the width of the div and image.

```
$(img).css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: ($(img).parent().width() - $(img).width()) / 2
});
```

This would mean:
((width of div)-(width of image))/2

This would center image perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

just do it like this.set the container's property "text-align:center",make  it is the inline-block element and 100% height，then can get what you want.

```
.image-wrap{
    width: 50vm;
    height: 720px;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-wrap img{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100vm;
}
```