# how to responsive design using bootstrap background image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I need to get the following background image responsive using bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="images\4.jpg">
</div>
```

How could I get the image responsive?

Comment: Please recreate your code in a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) and edit your question with the link attached. That will make it easier for people to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images not responsive by default in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932509/images-not-responsive-by-default-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1):

There is a responsive class for image in Bootstrap: 'img-fluid'. It will take up all the width of its container.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <img class="img-fluid" src="images\4.jpg">
</div>
```

Reference: [Bootstrap-4 responsive image](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images)

Comment: Please explain more about your question. :)

Comment: I have ackground image in My <div class="col-md-6"> bootstrap tag. now I need make responsive this image as well

Comment: Maybe this one will answer your question. [Image position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240058/center-image-inside-a-div-like-setting-background-position)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class="img-responsive"` to make any image responsive

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-6">
 <img src="http://theworldly.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/tech-wowcity.jpg" class="img-responsive">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with responsive background-image solution https://jsfiddle.net/tekx21t9/1/

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x15");
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-6 bg">
       <!--<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" />-->
     </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If you want the image tag to be there rather than background-image then below is the solution

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
     </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```